# Join a SQL resultset based on common email address

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one `table` that contains both students and parents records. There is a common field (email address) in both parent and student records that match the records (parents and students have the same email address).

> I want my query to find the common email addresses and return each
>   student record but it must also include a field (Mifare) from the
>   parents record.

So I have tried to join and where clauses but i am getting crazy results. I was also thinking of using the with clause.

Expected result is

[image]

The basic script is:

```
Select   extid,  first_name,  last_name,  commonemail, designation,mifare  
from students
```

Please assist with a basic coding - no procedures etc...just simple help for a newbie!

Thank you all!

Comment: which query you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
SELECT stud.ExtId,
stud.FirstName, 
stud.LastName, 
stud.CommonEmail,
stud.Designation,
stud.Mifare,
prnt.Mifare
FROM Students AS stud
INNER JOIN Students AS prnt
ON stud.CommonEmail = prnt.CommonEmail
AND stud.Designation = 'Student'
AND prnt.Designation = 'Parent'
```

You can also follow the link to the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b790b/1

Comment: This worked well - I had to add some other fields in to modify etc but it really worked

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can try this way join both the tables with email select only the designation student only.

```
Select
    st.extid,
    st.first_name,
    st.last_name,
    st.commonemail,
    st.designation,
    st. mifare
    pr.parentmifare
    from students st  inner join students pr on st.commonemail=pr.commonemail 
  where pr.designation='student' and st.designation='parent'
```

Comment: Thanks- this also worked and is similar to Nishants comment above

Answer (score 0):

```
Select s.*
p.mifare
from students s
left join students p on p.commonemail=s.commonemail and p.Designation='Parent'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following Sub query

```
Select  *,
(Select Mifare from students b where b.Designation = 'Parent' and b.commonemail = a.commonemail) as ParentMifare
from students a
```

Comment: Thanks - havent tried this but will - looks promising